# Bluez stuck authenticating when pairing airpods

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

After I hold the airpod button until it's LED turns white and flashes, I try pairing with

```
[bluetooth]# pair <mac-address>
```

which returns

```
Attempting to pair with 18:F1:D8:36:53:FB
```

However, it just stays there for a long time, until the airpod's LEDs turn green again and I get the following error

```
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled
```

which makes me believe that it is somehow stuck at the authentication step.

My airpod is able to pair on my other ubuntu machines and my android phone so I believe it is a problem of this computer's bluetooth settings.

### Output of `btmon`

```
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 47                                                                                                                                                    #3020 [hci0] 511.195393
      LE Extended Advertising Report (0x0d)
        Num reports: 1
        Entry 0
          Event type: 0x0010
            Props: 0x0010
              Use legacy advertising PDUs
            Data status: Complete
          Legacy PDU Type: ADV_NONCONN_IND (0x0010)
          Address type: Public (0x00)
          Address: 18:F1:D8:36:53:FB (Apple, Inc.)
          Primary PHY: LE 1M
          Secondary PHY: No packets
          SID: no ADI field (0xff)
          TX power: 0 dBm
          RSSI: -50 dBm (0xce)
          Periodic advertising invteral: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
          Direct address type: Public (0x00)
          Direct address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (OUI 00-00-00)
          Data length: 0x15
        14 ff 4c 00 07 0f 00 02 20 18 f1 d8 36 53 fb 15  ..L..... ...6S..
        e4 e4 52 01 00                                   ..R..
```

and

```
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 47                                                                                                                                                      #187 [hci0] 14.798946
      LE Extended Advertising Report (0x0d)
        Num reports: 1
        Entry 0
          Event type: 0x0010
            Props: 0x0010
              Use legacy advertising PDUs
            Data status: Complete
          Legacy PDU Type: ADV_NONCONN_IND (0x0010)
          Address type: Public (0x00)
          Address: 18:F1:D8:36:53:FB (Apple, Inc.)
          Primary PHY: LE 1M
          Secondary PHY: No packets
          SID: no ADI field (0xff)
          TX power: 0 dBm
          RSSI: -55 dBm (0xc9)
          Periodic advertising invteral: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
          Direct address type: Public (0x00)
          Direct address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (OUI 00-00-00)
          Data length: 0x15
        14 ff 4c 00 07 0f 00 02 20 18 f1 d8 36 53 fb 15  ..L..... ...6S..
        64 e1 52 01 00                                   d.R..
```

with the final output being

```
= bluetoothd: Pair device timed out for hci0                                                                                                                                                       [hci0] 577.933884
@ MGMT Command: Cancel Pair Device (0x001a) plen 7                                                                                                                                        {0x0001} [hci0] 577.933864
        LE Address: 18:F1:D8:36:53:FB (Apple, Inc.)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 10                                                                                                                                           {0x0001} [hci0] 577.933875
      Pair Device (0x0019) plen 7
        Status: Cancelled (0x10)
        LE Address: 18:F1:D8:36:53:FB (Apple, Inc.)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 10                                                                                                                                           {0x0001} [hci0] 577.933886
      Cancel Pair Device (0x001a) plen 7
        Status: Success (0x00)
        LE Address: 18:F1:D8:36:53:FB (Apple, Inc.)
```

### `/var/log/syslog` output

```
bluetoothd[1069]: src/adapter.c:device_found_callback() hci0 addr 18:F1:D8:36:53:FB, rssi -47 flags 0x0004 eir_len 21
bluetoothd[1069]: src/device.c:device_set_legacy() legacy 0
bluetoothd[1069]: src/device.c:device_set_rssi_with_delta() rssi -47 delta 8
bluetoothd[1069]: src/device.c:device_set_flags() flags 0
bluetoothd[1069]: src/agent.c:agent_ref() 0x556fdd8f6a90: ref=2
bluetoothd[1069]: src/device.c:bonding_request_new() Requesting bonding for 18:F1:D8:36:53:FB
bluetoothd[1069]: src/agent.c:agent_ref() 0x556fdd8f6a90: ref=3
bluetoothd[1069]: src/agent.c:agent_unref() 0x556fdd8f6a90: ref=2
bluetoothd[1069]: src/adapter.c:suspend_discovery()
bluetoothd[1069]: src/adapter.c:adapter_bonding_attempt() hci0 bdaddr 18:F1:D8:36:53:FB type 1 io_cap 0x04
bluetoothd[1069]: src/adapter.c:suspend_discovery_complete() status 0x00
bluetoothd[1069]: src/adapter.c:discovering_callback() hci0 type 7 discovering 0 method 0
bluetoothd[1069]: Pair device timed out for hci0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1063582/512217) solved my problem.  In particular, I had to set `ControllerMode = bredr` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`